# Magento custom product attribute not showing images in frontend

Tags: image, magento, wysiwyg, custom-attributes

For my magento 1.9.2 site I added custom product attribute `dimensions` with `Enable WYSIWYG` value set as `Yes`. For the products this field will contain image src values. But in frontend image values of this field is not showing.It shows as `<img width="240" height="40" test.png"}}"="" wysiwyg="" src="{{media url=" alt="t">`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Navigate on

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management -> Use Static
>   URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog to Yes

This will allow Magento to automatically add the full path to img src.

The bad side for this is that, it will no logger use {{media url=''}} but instead use the full path. So in case you have a testing website and you want to migrate the updated database to your live. You have to manually update also the path.

You can refer to this link http://www.thienphucvx.com/magento-tinymce-image-uploader-image-incorrect-url/